# How do I use Dynamic Programming to solve Knapsack

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm working on algorithms the classic Knapsack Problem (for MIT 6.002x) and also trying to get my head around Dynamic Programming.

The course doesn't cover DP, but asked me to go look it up. Which I have done but am none the wiser. Am finding it hard to relate to any of the tutorials / videos because they're mostly about solving other algorithms. And because I'm a bit fuzzy on DP to begin with they're not really helping.

Can anybody point me to a place that explains Dynamic Programming and how it is used to solve the Knapsack problem

Answer (score 3):

you can learn basics of dynamic programming and understand how knapsack problem can be solved using link below.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/

Comment: Thanks. That site seems to help. Will keep working on it